# Organizing Backbone.js one-page app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture

I have to make the one-page application in Backbone.js with a dozen of internal pages.

I decided to do it such way: every page is matched with appropriate function in Router object and consists of several Views, that representing special elements of page.

As for now, I made only two pages, but already have a total mess in a code - this pages and even internal views, that are almost completely different, have many common elements such as events handlers and another internal functions.

So, how it looks like now (briefly):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'main',
        'user/:username': 'account'
    },

    main: function() {
        new MainView();
    },

    account: function(username) {
        new AccountTopView();
        new AccountMiddleView();
    }
});

var LinkEvents = {
    'click a': 'navigate'
};

var navigate = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = event.currentTarget;
    var url = link.href;
    url = RemoveBaseUrl(url);
    app.navigate(url, {trigger: true});
}


var AccountMiddleView = ModalView.extend({
    template: _.template($('#tpl-account-middle').html()),

    events: _.extend(
        {},
        LinkEvents
    ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(
            this.template(

            )
        );
        return this;
    },

    navigate: navigate
});


var AccountTopView = ModalHatView.extend({
    template: _.template($('#tpl-account-top').html()),

    events: _.extend(
        {},
        LinkEvents
    ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(
            this.template(

            )
        );
        return this;
    },

    navigate: navigate
});
```

The real code is much larger, because there are already many events. Are there any ways to optimize such structure? And maybe any other advices?

Comment: There's a couple of ways to approach wrangling your growing complexity, but it's going to depend on the needs of your specific project. One, you can start creating base views that extend the basic Backbone views but contain your base, common functionality that you need to repeat in other views. Those views can then extend this base view. Another approach would be to use one of the extensions written for Backbone like Marionette, that do a lot of the Backbone boilerplate work for you and give you some additional structures to help manage complexit.

Comment: Thanks, also thought about Marionette, but not tried yet, so maybe now is a time.